# logger vs syslog -s

Tags: terminal, bash, script, command-line, logs

What exactly is the difference between using `logger` and `syslog -s`? According to its manpage, `logger` provides interface to the system log module, but I can't really see the point given that `syslog(1)` seems to be just that, only much more powerful.

Is it just a matter of simplicity or am I missing something? And which one would you recommend for simple scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`syslog` is more powerful than `logger` which also means that `logger` is easier to use for simple purposes. The man page indicates as much:

> man logger -> Logger provides a **shell command interface** to the syslog(3) system log module

The main advantage of `syslog -s` for simple logging is sending log lines to a different computer to have it logged there. For simple shell scripting that's probably not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Seems like it's more or less what I expected. However, as you can notice, the manpage you're citing mentions `syslog(3)` (the system log module), rather than `syslog(1)` (the command). In fact, `syslog(1)` isn't referred to at all in the whole `logger` manpage, even though it seems to provide "a shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module" just as well. I found it a bit confusing and hence my question!

Comment: (1) and (3) are chapter numbers in the man pages. 1 is commands, 3 is library calls. The facility itself is just syslog.